# Angular 4 model property

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 project I have a model like this:

```
export class DepositReceipt{
  euro1: number;
  euro2: number;
  euro5: number;
  euro10: number;
  euro20: number;
  euro50: number;
  euro100: number;
  euro200: number;
  euro500: number;
  totalAmount: number;
}
```

The property totalAmount actually is the sum of other properties, is it possible to define in the model something like: `totalAmount = euro500 + euro200 +...` 
Or if not possible how can I make it works?

When I have response from the server I like this field will be calculated automatically because it's the sum of others.

Comment: `get totalAmount() { return euro1 + euro2 + ...; }`? You should probably read the TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

Just define a getter:

```
export class DepositReceipt{
  euro1: number;
  euro2: number;
  euro5: number;
  euro10: number;
  euro20: number;
  euro50: number;
  euro100: number;
  euro200: number;
  euro500: number;
  get totalAmount() { return this.euro1 + this.euro2 + ... };
}
```

You then access `deposit.totalAmount` as though it were just an ordinary attribute, you don't call it as a function. (This may be stating the obvious but from your comment I'm not sure you realise it.)

Comment: OK, but without using any function, is it possible?

Comment: You don't call the attribute as a function if that's what you mean. I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple get function so instead of declaring totalAmount as a variable you can define it as:

```
get totalAmount() { return euro1 + euro2+ ...; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Your best bet is probably to write a getter and maybe cache the value.

```
_totalAmount: number;
get totalAmount(): number {
    if (this._totalAmount == undefined) {
        this._totalAmount = calculateTotalAmount();
    }
    return this._totalAmount;
}
```

Whenever you use the property, the getter will be called:

```
receipt.totalAmount // uses the getter automatically
```